Get Conditional Density from Joint Density in Abstract Setting
Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be real random variables defined on a common probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$. Let $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. We suppose that $X=(X_1,X_2)$ has joint distribution $f_X(x_1,x_2)d\nu(x_1,x_2)$ .
How do I express the value $\mathbb{E}[X_1 \mid X_2 = x_2]$ for a given $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ using integrals involving $f_X$ and $\nu$? In case of Lebesgue measure, this is very simple.
